# What is the difference between int type array's name and char type array's name ? (in C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int arr1[10]={1,2,3,4,5};
cout << "Address is : " << arr1 << endl;

char arr2[10] = "Hello";
cout << "Address is : " << arr2 << endl;
}
```

In this code, I expect that the adress of arr1 will printed first, and then the adress of arr2 also will printed second. Because the name of the array is the same as the starting address of the array.(arr = &arr[0])
However, But as a result of the execution, this is what it looks like.

Address is : 0x7ffde1799760
Address is : Hello

I wonder why printing arr2 does not print the starting address of the array, but the string stored in the array.

Thanks :)

Comment: `cout << "Address is : " << static_cast<void*>(arr2) << endl;`

Comment: Just read the manual "basic_ostream and character array" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2